# Lubridate periods get messed up after using dplyr spread

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, period, spread

I am using R-3.6.3, lubridate_1.7.4, dbplyr_1.4.2.

Reprex:

```
df_0 <- tibble(period_type  = c("a", "b", "c"), 
               period_value = c("1:1:1", "2:2:2", "4:4:4")) %>% 
        mutate(period_value = hms(period_value))

df_0
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  period_type period_value
#  <chr>       <Period>
#1 a           1H 1M 1S
#2 b           2H 2M 2S
#3 c           4H 4M 4S
```

So far so good.
Now using dplyr spread:

```
df_0 %>% spread(period_type, period_value)
## A tibble: 1 x 3
#  a        b        c
#  <Period> <Period> <Period>
#1 1H 1M 1S 1H 1M 2S 1H 1M 4S
```

But the result should be

```
## A tibble: 1 x 3
#  a        b        c
#  <Period> <Period> <Period>
#1 1H 1M 1S 2H 2M 2S 4H 4M 4S
```

Hours and minutes get messed up, but strangely not seconds.
Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `spread` is retired, so reporting weird results won't get much attention. Try `pivot_wider`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to `pivot_wider`.  More info in the [pivot vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Edward has commented, `pivot_wider()` has replaced `spread()`.  However, it doesn't seem to handle variables of period class.  So you need to convert the period values, pivot, then convert back.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df_0 %>%
  mutate(period_value = period_to_seconds(period_value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = period_type, values_from = period_value) %>%
  mutate_all(seconds_to_period)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  a        b        c       
  <Period> <Period> <Period>
1 1H 1M 1S 2H 2M 2S 4H 4M 4S
```

Comment: Indeed, `pivot-wider` alone does not solve the problem.  At least it throws an error: `df_0 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = period_type, values_from = period_value)Error: No common type for \`value\` <Period> and \`x\` <Period>.`.  Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: It's a strange error, though, so I still raised an issue on [github](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/916).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the tidyr verb, as [spread() isn't going away but is no longer under active development](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html)

Instead of lubridate, try function parse_hms() of package hms:

```
df_0 <- tibble(period_type  = c("a", "b", "c"), 
           period_value = c("1:1:1", "2:2:2", "4:4:4")) %>% 
  mutate(period_value = hms::parse_hms(period_value))

df_0 %>% spread(period_type, period_value)
# or
df_0 %>% pivot_wider(names_from=period_type, values_from=period_value)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  a        b        c       
  <time>   <time>   <time>  
1 01:01:01 02:02:02 04:04:04
```